# BitmapFactory.decodeResource() ignores inPreferredConfig option for jpg images

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, jpeg, decode

I try to load jpeg resource image to Bitmap of ARGB_8888 format:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId, opts);
Log.d("test", b.getConfig().toString());
```

Here *resId* is the id of a jpeg image resource. 
And the output is "**RGB_565**".
Tried this in emulators of android 2.2 and 2.3.

Docs of 'inPreferredConfig' say:

> If this is non-null, the decoder will try to decode into this internal
>   configuration. If it is null, or the request cannot be met, the
>   decoder will try to pick the best matching config based on the
>   system's screen depth, and characteristics of the original image such
>   as if it has per-pixel alpha (requiring a config that also does).
>   Image are loaded with the ARGB_8888 config by default.

So am I hitting the case of "*the request cannot be met*"? :)
But I honestly can't see how it is very difficult to decode RGB_565 into an ARGB_8888.

So I thought maybe I am doing wrong or this is a bug in Android...

Comment: Having the same issue. Solved yet?

Comment: Nope, not solved. IIRC I had to use a png instead of jpg...

Comment: I found out that my issue was my fault. Bitmap doesn't get loaded in RGB_565. It gets converted into in when I try to rotate it ('Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading jpeg you must set alpha channel to true:

```
bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the source I can only tell that the decision to follow the defined `inPreferredConfig` is done in native code. ref: [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L483)

I would assume because a jpg cannot have an alpha channel that it is decoding it `RGB_565` because it is the most efficient config for a non-alpha image. If you really want it to be decoded to `ARGB_8888` convert the image into a png.

Comment: Yep. I checked the source too, and saw that it is passed to the native code... Unfortunately currently I can't go on with png's because that would make my apk file too big - I have a lot of big jpg files packed into it, but that's another story :) Will wait for other answers a bit. Thanks for yours! :)